# How to add a progress bar to an ogr2ogr script

Tags: ogr2ogr

We have started using ogr2ogr to upload MapInfo tables into Microsoft SQL server in my workplace. Some of the tables are massive (>1,20,000 records) and there is no way of knowing how far the script has progressed without a status bar.

I was wondering if there is a command that can be used within the ogr2ogr script which actually tells us how much more of the processing is still left/pending (e.g. 50% complete etc.).

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for the `-progress` switch

```
ogr2ogr -progress ...
```

You can see the other options by doing `ogr2ogr --help`

```
Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
               [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where]
               [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>] [-dialect dialect]
               [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID]
               [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax]
               [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
               [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
               dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
               [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name] [-nlt type] [layer [layer ...]]

Advanced options :
               [-gt n]
               [-clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource|spat_extent]
               [-clipsrcsql sql_statement] [-clipsrclayer layer]
               [-clipsrcwhere expression]
               [-clipdst [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource]
               [-clipdstsql sql_statement] [-clipdstlayer layer]
               [-clipdstwhere expression]
               [-wrapdateline]
               [[-simplify tolerance] | [-segmentize max_dist]]
               [-fieldTypeToString All|(type1[,type2]*)]
               [-splitlistfields] [-maxsubfields val]
               [-explodecollections] [-zfield field_name]
```

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks a lot for such a quick response. Really appreciate your help. I'm a complete novice in ogr2ogr. Are you able to provide an example of a typical SQL statement that must go in the SQL argument? What about the dialect?

Again, thanks for your help!

Cheers,
VG