# How can I subtract one (very very large) set of features from another?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I'm trying to subtract a very large set of features (water areas) from another, relatively small set of features (land area).

In principle, I should be able to do this in QGIS using `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference`, but as the very large set of water features is *very large* (a 1.7GB shapefile), this is taking... a while. (Given that the progress bar on running a small subset of it has not budged in 14 hours, I am reasonably convinced it has crashed.)

What's the best way of doing this? Can I do it with gdal or ogr or a python library? Will it be more likely to work if I merge all the separate water features into a single feature? (Currently there are about 2.2 million, and I don't actually care about the water features, only the land.)

Comment: It is likely that it works better with a single feature because you have a loop for each feature with this tool for each combination of features from both files. Not entirly sure as it might be that it loops over the feature-parts the same way. But its worth a try. The other features are not that different, so the general outcome will be a long process.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest *dissolving* (`Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve`) your water area shapefile to a single feature (as mentioned by @Matte) before running the **Difference** tool.

You could do this inside QGIS but since it's a large file, I would probably suggest using ogr in the **OSGeo4W Shell**. Example:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" dissolved.shp input.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_union(Geometry),common_attribute from input GROUP BY common_attribute"
```

Then with the output, you can run the **Difference** tool.

Comment: I'm running this now, but it's also taking a very long time (not especially surprising). Is there a way to run it with a progress bar or at least a verbose mode so I could see that it's still doing something? (I didn't see anything obvious in the ogr2ogr docs.)

Comment: @futuraprime - Not surprising at all =). Try adding `-progress` after calling `ogr2ogr` (e.g. `ogr2ogr -progress -f "ESRI Shapefile"...` as mentioned in [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67573/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-an-ogr2ogr-script).